# How to convert Date and Time with mailmerge google slides from sheets as it is in cell

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, time, google-slides-api

[image]

I have created a table with which I can record our check in times of our employees with the help of a generated Qr code in each line.The data in the table is generated as slides and converted into pdf. For this I use a script that I got to work with your help and it works. Here I would like to thank you especially @tanaike.

My problem is that the date and time are not copied to the slides to be generated as indicated in the cell but completely with Central European time and I added in the script to look in column if its empty to generate the slide. If it's not empty don't do anything. As I said everything is working except this two things.

I must confess I did not try to correct it somehow because I had already shot the script and I made some here despair. It would be really great if you write me the solutions and I can take them over. I will share the spreadsheet with you and the screenshot with ae and time. Thanks for your time and effort to help people like us; we are really trying.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14cyHIzdBHSFa4hgj0S0bCIFk7CC-zSw4g3ngI7UNgcQ/edit?usp=sharing    The spreasheet I am using

Comment: The example I said in the second Row.As you can see i wrote for the DAte in The collumn E  26.01.2023 and it merged to the slide as above in the screenshot. If i write 26012023 it merged to the slides as it is. Same with the times in Collumn H and I. I want in that collumn write 26.01.2023 an 18:00 19:00 The script should also take it over in the slides. Thx for your Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another approach, when I saw your question, I thought that if your Spreadsheet has the correct date values you expect, and in your script, you are retrieving the values using `getValues`, `getValues` is replaced with `getDisplayValues()`, it might be your expected result.

When I saw your provided sample Spreadsheet, I found your current script, when your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var sheetContents = dataRange.getValues();
```

#### To:

```
sheetContents = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
```

#### Note:

- When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that the column of the date has mixed values of both the string value and the date object. So, if you want to use the values as the date object using `getValues`, please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

### Added:

About your 2nd question of `I mean that when a slide has been generated, the script saves the link from the slide in column D if the word YES is in column L. How do I make the script create the slide if there is JA in the column L and there is no link in column D. is a link in column D, the script should not generate a slide again. Thus, the script should only generate a slide if column D is empty and at the same time the word JA is in column L.`, when I proposed to modify from `if (row[2] === "" && row[11] === "JA") {` to `if (row[3] == "" && ["JA", "YES"].includes(row[11])) {`, you say as follows.

> If ichanged as you descripted if (row[3] == "" && ["JA", "YES"].includes(row[11])) { i got this error. Syntax error: Unexpected token 'else' Line: 21 File: Code.gs

In this case, I'm worried that you might correctly reflect my proposed script. Because when I tested it, no error occurs. So, just in case, I add the modified script from your provided Spreadsheet as follows. Please test this.

#### Modified script:

```js
function mailMergeSlidesFromSheets() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  sheetContents = dataRange.getDisplayValues(); // Modified
  sheetContents.shift();
  var updatedContents = [];
  var check = 0;
  sheetContents.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[3] == "" && ["JA", "YES"].includes(row[11])) { // Modified
      check++;
      var slides = createSlidesFromRow(row);
      var slidesId = slides.getId();
      var slidesUrl = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${slidesId}/edit`;
      updatedContents.push([slidesUrl]);

      slides.saveAndClose();
      var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?exportFormat=pdf&id=${slidesId}`, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob().setName(slides.getName() + ".pdf");
      DriveApp.getFolderById("1tRC505IWtTj8nnPB7XyydvTtCJmOb6Ek").createFile(pdf);
      // Or DriveApp.getFolderById("###folderId###").createFile(pdf);
    } else {
      updatedContents.push([row[3]]);
    }
  });
  if (check == 0) return;
  sheet.getRange(2, 4, updatedContents.length).setValues(updatedContents);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support it worked again as usual. But as i descripted above how can i say the script to look in the column foe a generated link and if there is a link inside donta generate. And if no link is inside generate the slide. So i think i can solve the time out Problem from google appscript. Or what do you think is it possible?

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. From `Thank you for your support it worked again as usual.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But as i descripted above how can i say the script to look in the column foe a generated link and if there is a link inside donta generate. And if no link is inside generate the slide.`. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, what is `a link inside donta generate`?

Comment: @ Tanaike thx for your reply.I mean that when a slide has been generated, the script saves the link from the slide in column D if the word YES is in column L. How do I make the script create the slide if there is JA in the column L and there is no link in column D.  is a link in column D, the script should not generate a slide again. Thus, the script should only generate a slide if column D is empty and at the same time the word JA is in column L. I hope I somehow got it

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. You want to run the script when column "D" has no URL and column "L" has a value of `YES` or `JA`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Pavlos Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your 2nd question, when I saw your script in your sample Spreadsheet, you are using `if (row[2] === "" && row[11] === "JA") {`. In this case, the columns "C" and "L" are confirmed. If you want to check the columns "D" and "L", please modify it to `if (row[3] == "" && ["JA", "YES"].includes(row[11])) {`, and test it again. If you want to check only the value of `JA`, please modify to `if (row[3] == "" && row[11] == "JA") {`.

Comment: thx for your Support. If ichanged as you descripted if (row[3] == "" && ["JA", "YES"].includes(row[11])) {  i got this error.  Syntax error: Unexpected token 'else' Line: 21 File: Code.gs

Comment: @Pavlos Thank you for replying. About `If ichanged as you descripted if (row[3] == "" && ["JA", "YES"].includes(row[11])) { i got this error. Syntax error: Unexpected token 'else' Line: 21 File: Code.gs `, I'm worried that you might correctly reflect my proposed script. Because when I tested it, no error occurs. So, please provide your Spreadsheet including your current script for correctly replicating it.

Comment: @Pavlos I'm worried that you might correctly reflect my proposed script. So, I added the modified script from your provided Spreadsheet. Please confirm it.

Comment: Arigatoo! it is working as I want. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
function todaysDateAndTime() {
  const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM:dd:yyyy");
  const tm = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"HH:mm:ss");
  Logger.log(dt);
  Logger.log(tm);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably I expressed myself wrongly because with your function the slide remains as is. I want that in the slide only the dtum and the time is taken over and not as shown in the screenshot. That means it should stay as shown in the table. Just as numbers.